# Ignore warning Python

Tags: python, warnings

I have python script with following piece of code:

```
def refreshRoot():
    global root
    try:
        root.destroy()
    except:
        pass
    else:
        global root
    ...
```

This code returns SyntaxWarning which causes execution by double-clicking the icon to fail. Window simply doesn't open... So can I somehow prevent this warning from occuring?

Comment: It's *very* bad idea to ever ignore warnings. Fix the code instead: the second global declaration is unnecessary.

Comment: If I don't have second global declaration, it doesn't always consider `root` recreated afterwards global and it crashes...

Comment: Hmm. I'd have to see the rest of the code to diagnose that.

Comment: Have you tried `warnings` package? Check [this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/warnings.html#temporarily-suppressing-warnings) if you haven't. Or else compile with `python -W ignore ScriptName.py`

Answer (score 0):

This will suppress all SyntaxWarning.

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=SyntaxWarning)
```

If you want to learn more, you can read [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html).